# Add Depth to Each Instance's Quadtree Nodes

Tags: python, image-processing, computer-vision, quadtree

How can I modify the code shown below to apply different depth level of quadtree to each instance contained in the image. I would like to apply a finer quadtree level on instances such as the 'teddy bear' and 'plant' while a coarse quadtree level on the 'background', 'table' and 'plant vase' instances.

**EFFORTS UNDERTAKEN SO FAR (BIT LONG TO READ)**
I have an image such that each x,y coordinate already has a value associated based on the instance as follows:

```
INSTANCE      PIXEL VALUE
background     0.0
chair          1.0
table          2.0
teddy bear     3.0
plant          4.0
vase           5.0
```

This is what the image looks like when plotted as follows

```
img_arr = np.loadtxt("seg_mask_retrieved.txt")
mask_image = plt.imshow(img_arr, cmap='hot', interpolation='nearest')
```

[image: instance based pixels]

I am able to perform instance value based quadtree (Results shown at the end). All I need now is to modify this code in order to add depth level based on each instance:

```
import numpy as np
import math

class Point:
    def __init__(self, x, y):
        self.x = x
        self.y = y
    
    def distanceToCenter(self, center):
        return math.sqrt((center.x-self.x)**2 + (center.y-self.y)**2)

class Rectangle:
    def __init__(self, center, width, height):
        self.center = center
        self.width = width
        self.height = height
        self.west = center.x - width
        self.east = center.x + width
        self.north = center.y - height
        self.south = center.y + height

    def containsPoint(self, point):
        return (self.west <= point.x < self.east and 
                self.north <= point.y < self.south)
    
    def intersects(self, range):
        return not (range.west > self.east or
                    range.east < self.west or
                    range.north > self.south or
                    range.south < self.north)
    

    def draw(self, ax, c='g', lw=1, **kwargs):
        x1, y1 = self.west, self.north
        x2, y2 = self.east, self.south
        ax.plot([x1,x2,x2,x1,x1], [y1,y1,y2,y2,y1], c=c, lw=lw, **kwargs)

class QuadTree:
    def __init__(self, boundary, capacity = 1):
        self.boundary = boundary
        self.capacity = capacity
        self.points = []
        self.instances = []
        self.unique_instances = []
        self.divided = False

    def insert(self, point, instance):
        # if the point is in the range of current quadTree
        if not self.boundary.containsPoint(point):
            return False

        if self.divided:
            if self.nw.insert(point, instance):
                return True
            elif self.ne.insert(point, instance):
                return True
            elif self.sw.insert(point, instance):
                return True
            elif self.se.insert(point, instance):
                return True
            else:
                assert "Should never happen"
        else:
            # if has not reached capcaity
            instance_already_seen = instance in self.unique_instances
            if instance_already_seen or len(self.unique_instances) < self.capacity:
                self.points.append(point)
                self.instances.append(instance)
                if not instance_already_seen:
                    self.unique_instances.append(instance)
                return True
            
            self.divide()
            assert self.insert(point, instance)

        return True

    def queryRange(self, range):
        found_points = []

        if not self.boundary.intersects(range):
            return []

        if self.divided:
            found_points.extend(self.nw.queryRange(range))
            found_points.extend(self.ne.queryRange(range))
            found_points.extend(self.sw.queryRange(range))
            found_points.extend(self.se.queryRange(range))
        else:
            for point in self.points:
                if range.containsPoint(point):
                    found_points.append(point)

        return found_points

    def queryRadius(self, range, center):
        if not self.boundary.intersects(range):
            return []

        found_points = []

        if self.divided:
            found_points.extend(self.nw.queryRadius(range, center))
            found_points.extend(self.ne.queryRadius(range, center))
            found_points.extend(self.sw.queryRadius(range, center))
            found_points.extend(self.se.queryRadius(range, center))
        else:
            for point in self.points:
                if range.containsPoint(point) and point.distanceToCenter(center) <= range.width:
                    found_points.append(point)

        return found_points

    def divide(self):
        center_x = self.boundary.center.x
        center_y = self.boundary.center.y
        new_width = self.boundary.width / 2
        new_height = self.boundary.height / 2

        nw = Rectangle(Point(center_x - new_width, center_y - new_height), new_width, new_height)
        self.nw = QuadTree(nw)

        ne = Rectangle(Point(center_x + new_width, center_y - new_height), new_width, new_height)
        self.ne = QuadTree(ne)

        sw = Rectangle(Point(center_x - new_width, center_y + new_height), new_width, new_height)
        self.sw = QuadTree(sw)

        se = Rectangle(Point(center_x + new_width, center_y + new_height), new_width, new_height)
        self.se = QuadTree(se)

        self.divided = True

        self.unique_instances = []
        for (point, instance) in zip(self.points, self.instances):
            assert self.insert(point, instance)

        self.points = []
        self.instances = []

    def __len__(self):
        if self.divided:
            return len(self.nw) + len(self.ne) + len(self.sw) + len(self.se)
        else:
            return len(self.points)
    
    def draw(self, ax):
        if self.divided:
            self.nw.draw(ax)
            self.ne.draw(ax)
            self.se.draw(ax)
            self.sw.draw(ax)
        else:
            self.boundary.draw(ax)
```

The code is run using the following commands

```
import numpy as np
import matplotlib.pyplot as plt
from matplotlib import gridspec
from quadtree import Point, Rectangle, QuadTree

DPI = 72

INPUT_FILE = 'seg_mask_retrieved.npy'

mask_image = np.load(INPUT_FILE)

height, width = mask_image.shape

domain = Rectangle(Point(width/2, height/2), width/2, height/2)
qtree = QuadTree(domain)


for y in range(height):
    for x in range(width):
        assert qtree.insert(Point(x, y), mask_image[y, x])

print('Total points: ', len(qtree))

# draw rectangles
fig = plt.figure(figsize=(700/DPI, 500/DPI), dpi=DPI)
ax = plt.subplot()
ax.imshow(mask_image, cmap='hot', interpolation='nearest')
ax.set_xlim(0, width)
ax.set_ylim(0, height)
qtree.draw(ax)

ax.invert_yaxis()
plt.tight_layout()
plt.savefig('search-quadtree.png', DPI=72)
plt.show()
```

The output looks like this

[image]

After adding depth to each instance, the output should somewhat look like this (only the chair instance has been modified to show the output just for demonstration of a coarse quadtree)

[image: depth level for each instance]